# Why is this code producing UnboundLocalError

Tags: python

```
                        #this is my level system
                        player_level = 1
                        player_xp = 100
                        if player_xp == 1000:player_level = 2 
                        elif player_xp == 2500:player_level = 3
                        elif player_xp == 3500:player_level = 4
                        elif player_xp == 5000:player_level = 5
                        elif player_xp == 6500:player_level = 6
                        elif player_xp == 8000:player_level = 7
                        elif player_xp == 9500:player_level = 8
                        elif player_xp == 15000:player_level = 9
                        elif player_xp == 30000:player_level = 10
                        elif player_xp == 60000:player_level = 11
                        elif player_xp == 120000:player_level = 12
                        elif player_xp > 120000:player_xp = 120000
                        #this checks if your a high enough level 
                        if player_level == (10,12):
                                caniget = True
                        elif player_level == (1,9):
                                caniget = False
```

## this is where it keeps coming up with UnboundLocalError is says UnboundLocalError: local variable 'caniget' referenced before assignment.

```
                        if caniget: What = {"OOF": random.randint(18, 10000),
                                     "Power Sword": random.randint(10, 21000),
                                     "Mega heal": random.randint(20, 10000)}
                        #im using visual stdio code
```

Answer (score 0):

`caniget` is a global variable.  If you assign to a global variable in a function you must declare the variable global.  You can, however, read global variables without declaration.

Here's a small module as an example:

```
caniget = 0

def demo():
    if caniget == 0:
        print('It is zero')

def demo2():
    if caniget == 1:
        print('It is one')
        caniget = 0

def demo3():
    global caniget
    if caniget == 0:
        print('It is zero')
        caniget = 1
```

`demo` reads the variable with no issue.  Python looks for a local variable of that name, doesn't find it, and then looks at the global namespace and finds it.

`demo2` assigns to the variable.  If a function assigns to a variable without global anywhere in the function, it is assumed to be a local  variable, so at the `if` statement, the local variable hasn't been assigned yet.  Python knows it is a local variable and throws the error you are receiving.

`demo3` declares the variable global, and has no issue.

```
>>> import demo
>>> demo.demo()
It is zero
>>> demo.demo2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\demo.py", line 8, in demo2
    if caniget == 1:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'caniget' referenced before assignment
>>> demo.demo3()
It is zero
>>> demo.demo3()
>>>                    # and now it is not zero :)
```

Comment: I will try, even if it does not work this is a very usful piece of information.

Comment: @imapancake You haven't shown enough code to precisely fix your issue, but this is the only reason to get an UnboundLocalError.